# Create executable with Python, which use QT and different versions of python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I am planning to make a self contained app on OSX, which use a QT/PYQT UI with Python3, and also code using Python2 (because the libraries I use are not available on Python3 yet).

I am using Pyinstaller; which create apps that works fine on my machine, but when I try the same app on a different machine I get crashes or errors.

I was under the impression that `Pyinstaller` does generate a self contained app, but it seems that I still need to install QT on the computers that will run this app? Is there a better way to generate self contained apps, that would work in my scenario?

Comment: If you are using qt, you might want to look into this `https://www.smallsurething.com/a-really-simple-guide-to-packaging-your-pyqt-application-with-cx_freeze/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying pure python apps with `Pyinstaller` is straight forward but it comes tricky especially with a framework like pyqt. The best results i got so far was using `cx_freeze` which makes sure that all the dependencies are packaged correctly.

**Here is an extensive walkthrough:**
https://www.smallsurething.com/a-really-simple-guide-to-packaging-your-pyqt-application-with-cx_freeze/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; I will give it a try. Also the fact that it works on various platforms, is really helpful, if I plan to move the app also on windows.

Comment: In general deploying `Qt` is a pain, even in the `C++` lib.

Comment: Does CX-Freeze care if the python script is calling code in another script, that require a different version of Python? That was my second issue with packaging everything in one app. Thanks!

Comment: cx_freeze tries to find the dependencies and adds them to the container where your app is launched from. If you get errors that some packages are not included, you can always update the config your self as well.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I have everything in a single pycharm project; but some files are running from 2.6 and others from 3.2; if Pycharm can find all the required dependencies, I am positive that CX_Freeze will be able to find them.